# How to replace switch statement with more flexible code in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have table called **posts** in my DB. Each **post** has field called **social_network**

When I get all **posts** into array in my code I need to create instances for each one based on it's **social_network** field.

Right now I use switch statement for this but I don't like it as it is not flexible.

```php
$posts = DataBase::getPosts(); // pseudocode
foreach($posts as $post) {
  switch($post->getSocialNetwork()){
    case 'Facebook':
      $social = new FacebookPost($post->getId());
      break;
    case 'Twitter':
      $social = new TwitterPost($post->getId());
      break;        
    // .... other social networks
  }
}
```

Comment: how it is not flexible in what you are doing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an interface to the classes FacebookPost and TwitterPost (eg SocialPostInterface) that has defined same basic necessary methods like `getId()`, `postToNetwork()` Then you can add as many new social networks as you want, without having to change this piece of code. They just have to implement the interface

Then experience the power of polymorhpism:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $className = $post->getSocialNetwork() . 'Post';
    // lets check if such class exists
    if (!class_exists($className, false /* do not attempt autoload */)) {
        throw new Exception("Unknown social network post class $className");
    }
    $social = new $className($post->getId());
    $social->doSomeStuffThatTheInterfaceHasDeclared();
}
```

Comment: based on his code, he is already using polymorphism... also, PHP uses duck typing, there's no force to use a common ancestor or interface (though it is a good idea to use it as documentation)

Comment: I am going to use this code in PostFactory class. Will it be right use?

Comment: @DampeS8N my first comment was for Karoly Horvath, sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: @Veseliq: dear humor herold, I just reflected on your sentence ("Then experience the power of polymorhpism"). also note, that what is obvious to us, can be an important insight to a beginner.

Comment: You can validate against certain interfaces:


`$interfaces = class_implements($className);
if (!isset($interfaces['Some\\Namespace\\MyInterface'])) { 
    throw new Exception("Class $className does not implement the right interfaces"); 
}`

Answer (score 4):

I dont think you can avoid this sort of code.  however you may want to move it into an abstract factory, so you don't have to look at it in your controller.

```
$posts = DataBase::getPosts(); // pseudocode
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $social = SocialFactory::post($post);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is just plain factory method - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
$socialClass = $post->getSocialNetwork() . 'Post';
$social = new $socialClass($post->getId());
```

You can make a new object from a string holding its name.